# Merge nested dictionaries and update keys

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have read through lots about nested merging, but could find a way to merge dictionaries properly, even in an infinite dictionary nest.
Can someone help me out please.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictA ={"core":{"globals":{"qmenu_object_name":"menu2",
                            "metadata_label":"label1"},
        "load_plug":True}}

dictB = {"core":{"globals":{"widget_name":"widgetA"}}}
mydicts = [dictA, dictB]
result = defaultdict(dict)
for d in mydicts:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result[k].update(v)
```

## I expect this:

```
dictA ={"core":{"globals":{"qmenu_object_name":"menu2",
                            "metadata_label":"label1",
                            "widget_name":"widgetA"},
        "load_plug":True}}
```

## But I get this:

```
"core":{"globals":{"widget_name":"widgetA"}, 'load_plug': True}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need a general solution, not just one for your example `dictA` and `dictB`, correct?

Comment: dict.update() do add new keys or overwrite existing keys. I assume, if you need infinite deep, you should write some recursion func